# How to configure openstack horizon to use https

Tags: https, openstack, openstack-horizon

Installed queens version in centos VM using pack stack installer.i want to configure openstack horizon to use https. Can any one help?

Comment: Did you check? https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/pike/admin/customize-configure.html#configure-the-dashboard-for-https